# How to paste multiple columns of two different files with paste?

Tags: bash, macos

Using this data:

```
$cat file1
8.0     175.0
9.0     405.8
10.0    844.8
11.0    307.2

$cat file2
8.0     188.5
9.0     428.6
10.0    945.7
11.0    335.9
```

How can I merge these to together linewise. I tried several possibilities with `paste`like simply:

```
$paste file1 file2
```

The problem is that I get three columns where the middle one is merged from two original ones:

```
8.0     8.0.5   175.0
9.0     9.0.6   405.8
10.0    10.07   844.8
11.0    11.09   307.2
```

The result I'd like to have looks like this:

```
8.0     175.0    8.0    188.5
9.0     405.8    9.0    428.6
10.0    844.8    10.0   945.7
11.0    307.2    11.0   335.9
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Paste should insert a tab between each two pasted lines, so the output should look a lot like your example.

Comment: When I recreate your example I get the output you specified. The only difference is that I don't get leading space on the first two lines.

Comment: The leading space wasn't intended. Sorry. May the reason be that I use OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files have \r\n line endings, so the first line is actually:

```
8.0\t175.0\r\t8.0\t188.5\r\n
#^^^^^^^^^^^..^^^^^^^^^^^^
# file1         file2
#          tab added by paste
```

run `dos2unix` or `sed -i.bak 's/\r$//'` on your files.

Comment: BTW, your "mangled" output was from the command `paste file2 file1`